# How to solve this differential equation ?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{1}{L} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$$

The solution is given as $$u = \exp(-\frac{1}{L}x) + 0.2 ,$$ with far field boundary condition as $u_\infty=0.2$.

Can anyone tell how does one end up with that kind of solution ?

Comment: Try solving the characteristic equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we can integrate with respect to $x$:
$$u' +\frac u L = c_0, \quad c_0\text{ is a constant}$$

This is easy to integrate (hint: look at the derivative $\left(\exp\left(\frac xL\right)u\right)'$), too, it gives 
$$\exp\left(\frac xL\right)u=Lc_0\exp\left(\frac xL\right) +c_1,$$or
$$u=Lc_0 +c_1\exp\left(-\frac xL\right)$$
Plug your boundary conditions for $x\to+\infty$, it would give you $Lc_0=0.2$. You will need some other condition to conclude that $c_1=1$.

**edit**
How to solve a differential equation for constant $a$ and $b$ $$u' + au = b$$
The standard trick is to multiply by a well-chosen exponent in order to obtain "a derivative of a product" on the left-hand side. We know that $(\exp(ct))' = c\exp(ct)$, so what happens if we multiply both sides by $\exp(at)$:
$$u'(t)\exp(at) + a\exp(at)u(t) = \left(u(t)\exp(at)\right)' = b\exp(at).$$
Now we have a derivative on the left-hand side and something that does not depend on $u$ on the right-hand side, so we can happily integrate:
$$u(t) \exp(at) = \frac{b}{a}\exp(at) + d.$$
Multiply by $\exp(-at)$ to arrive to the final result. This approach has multiple generalizations, but the idea remains the same - multiply the equation to recover a derivative of a product in order to reduce the number of terms containing the derivative of the unknown function.

Comment: Thanks. Can you briefly explain the second line..how do you get that without looking at the solution?

Comment: @newstudent see edit